# Getting numerous compiler errors on brand new mvc5/web.api app in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api

Here is a screenshot of all the errors:

[image: List of compiler errors]

ive done all the NuGet updates and reinstalls and downgrades I can possibly do as well as follow ALLOT of the suggestions that came close to my issue from microsoft's community site as well as stackoverflow with no resolution.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

What am I missing or need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: what .net framework are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Can you check in your reference list have Microsoft.CSharp and System or not?

Comment: Yes, I have those references. I also tried to unreference it and re add it to the references (system.web.mvc) still no resolution.

Comment: Looks like it maybe a problem with VS2015. Because I do not get the errors in VS2013

Comment: Reinstalled VS2015 - apparently this solved the issue.